# User and Session sharing among multiple Laravel 8 sites under the same domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Before anyone tells me to Google it - I did and followed the instructions on this link:

https://medium.com/@zsolt.gyure96/how-to-share-sessions-between-two-laravel-applications-4b9d061fa599

Below is my setup: I have a group of sites that are all under the same domain hosted under different directories. I use virtual host aliasing to point them. For example, alias blog points to example.com/blog. Now, I would like to share the users and sessions among my apps. I followed the instructions in the above article and created a common_database that manages all the user data and sessions. My apps can read the sessions table. I also have the same session set up as my domain.

By adding

```
       protected $connection = 'common_database';
```

in the following files I can login and register from example.com/blog/login or register routes.

1. vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/RegistersUsers.php
2. vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php Instead added

The only problem I have now is that there is no session sharing.  For example if i login example.com/blog/login then I cannot use the same session for example.com or example.com/news.  I have to re-login.   What am I missing here?

Comment: did you forget to set the APP_KEY across all the sites to the same value ?

Comment: No its all the same value.

Comment: As matter of fact when I login to one instance it logs me out from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will work for you but what I did was instead of using SESSSION_DRIVER=database I used  SESSSION_DRIVER=cookie  on .env file make sure your APP_KEY is the same for both projects.

Answer (score 0):

SESSION_DRIVER was not set to the database in the main site's .env.